# Recurring events are not expanded from Yahoo with caldav4j

Tags: java, icalendar, caldav, ical4j

I have one problem with loading expanded events from Yahoo using caldav4j. I have one recurring event that occurs every Monday starting from 1.11.2017 to 30.12.2017.

I'm creating query for that range and using this for expand:

```
gq.setRecurrenceSet(START,END, CalendarData.EXPAND);
```

where gq is `GenerateQuery` instance.

The result is that I got only one event and I was expecting that it will be expanded to 9 single events. Am I missing something?

Here is created query that was sent to Yahoo:

```
C:calendar-query xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
    <D:prop xmlns:D="DAV:">
        <D:getetag/>
        <D:allprop/>
        <C:calendar-data>
            <C:comp name="VCALENDAR"/>
            <C:expand end="20180101T000000Z" start="20171010T000000Z"/>
        </C:calendar-data>
    </D:prop>
    <C:filter>
        <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
            <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">
                <C:time-range end="20180101T000000Z" start="20171010T000000Z"/>
                <C:prop-filter name="STATUS">
                    <C:text-match caseless="yes"
                        collation="i;ascii-casemap" negate-condition="yes">CANCELLED</C:text-match>
                </C:prop-filter>
            </C:comp-filter>
        </C:comp-filter>
    </C:filter>
</C:calendar-query>
```

I can probably create it myself using ical4j and getPeriods() for event, but if there is an option with this, it would be nice.

Any ideas? Thanks!